# What is the supremum of the set?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

What is the supremum of the set consisting the following real numbers:

• 0.200 . . .

• 0.2500 . . .

• 0.25200 . . .

• 0.252500 . . .

Would it just be 0.252500?

Comment: Just these four numbers?  Then, yes.  The supremum of a finite set is the largest element of that set.  But it looks like you are just writing the first terms of a sequence.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Assuming the pattern continues the way I think it does, $0.2525$ is going to be too small to be a supremum, as the next number in the sequence, $0.25252$ is larger.

Answer (score 2):

The supremum is

$$25 \left(\frac{1}{100} + \left(\frac{1}{100}\right)^2 + \dots\right) = \frac{25}{100}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{100}}=\frac{25}{99}$$

Comment: Which is indeed 0.2525252525.... (25 being repeated indefinitely)